# Missing center point in scatter plot on matplotlib PolarAxes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to draw markers on a matplotlib `PolarAxes` using `plot` or `scatter` (tried both).

Here is my code (not showing the part that creates the  plot and colorbar):

```py
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
axes: plt.Axes = figure.add_axes(
    position, 
    projection="polar"
)
axes.plot(
    apos, rpos, 'o',
    markersize=4,
    markerfacecolor='white',
    markeredgecolor='darkgrey'
)
```

The data, whith angular and radial positions `apos` and `rpos`, clearly contains the center points with coordinates (0, 0); in total it's 49 points.

[image]

The problem is that the center point is always missing on the resulting plot.

[image]

In fact, if I manipulate the data and increase the radial position of the first point from `0` to `5` or higher, the corresponding marker suddenly appears. For radii < 5, no marker is drawn.

I'd like to understand why this is not working as intended and how I can fix it so that the center point does appear on the plot.

This is using python 3.8.10 and matplotlib 3.2.2.

In case anyone is interested, this is a visualization of a wafer-map measurement of sheet resistance on a 8" silicon wafer coated with a Cu thin film. The markers indicate the sites of the 49-point measurement pattern.

Comment: Cannot reproduce locally, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be related to the axes limits. The polar meshgrid-data used to fill the plot area has a 'hole' in the middle (the white area in the graphic below). Matplotlib automatically adjusted the axes limits. The solution was to explicitly set the axes limits to inlcude r=0 using `set_ylim()`, which corresponds to the readial axis in a polar plot.

[image]